How do I enable auto-scrolling in Gnome?
I am using Debian Bookworm; Gnome 43.9; Wayland windowing system; Kernel 6.1.0-18-amd64
I was able to use
xinput list
xinput set-prop 11 "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 0, 0, 1  # This is button
xinput set-prop 11 "libinput Button Scrolling Button" 2      # This is middle mouse. Already 2 by default
11 is the ID of my rf mouse (found through xinput list)

in cinnamon
but this requires libinput also Xwayland doesn't play nicely with xinput for some reason.
could someone please help me find a way to achieve the same result through Xwayland without installing libinput if it is possible?
